# React: Pass incoming service data to children

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I am working on a React project that connects to a websocket and receives live data. Currently I have a Websocket component that handles the data in callback. I need to be able to get this incoming data to multiple different child components. I am not sure what the best way to do this is. I am trying to stick with functional components since this seems to be what React is moving to.

Here is some demo code as an example.

```
function Parent() {
    const handleData = function callback(data) {
        console.debug(data);
    };

    return (
            <div className="container-main">
                <Websocket url='ws://localhost:8000/Service/' onMessage={handleData}/>
                <Child />
            </div>
    );
}

export default Parent;

function Child() {
    return (
        <div>Websocket Message</div>
    );
}

export default Child;
```

You can see that the data is coming in and being handled by the handleData callback. From there I would like to update the Websocket Message in the child with the data.

It is possible that I am thinking about this the wrong way as well. If there is a better way to structure it I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass any values you want to all children. It will look something like this:

```
// Parent
function Parent() {
  return (
    <div className="container-main">
      <Websocket url='ws://localhost:8000/Service/'>
        <Child />
      </Websocket>
    </div>
  );
}

// Websocket
const WebsocketContext = React.createContext();

function Websocket({children}) {
  const [websocketData, setWebsocketData] = useState({});

  // websocket logic that sets and updates state that is passed to WebsocketContext

  return (
    <WebsocketContext.Provider value={{setWebsocketData, websocketData}}>
      {children}
    </WebsocketContext.Provider>
  );
}

//Child
function Child() {
  const websocketData = useContext(WebsocketContext);
  return (
    <div>Websocket Message</div>
  );
}
```

This composes quite nicely and allows any/all children to subscribe to the context as needed.